# How to check if list of int in the list of string?

Tags: python

I have 2 defauldict(list); one of them only display the number and another one contain the whole line  of text.

I have list of int (lookup)

```
[112, 896, 455, 1164, 1164, 336, 386, 521, 1011, 1033]
```

and list of string (description)

```
[['ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057393', 'p.Tyr112His', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296091', '-'],
 ['ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057394', 'p.Thr896Ala', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296093', '-'],...]
```

I am trying to come up with `if` statement to check while i run the program, basically, when i use number that match the line, i want to print the line of that string for example, if i use number 112, which match the first line (p.Tyr112His), i want to have it print the whole line that contains p.Tyr112His; which is:

> 'ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057393', 'p.Tyr112His', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296091', '-'.

Comment: Does your code work? If not, why not? Give examples. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Marcin i don't know how to use the if statement to test that. This code just give me 2 list one that contain int and string.

Comment: Your comment is not the same thing as putting in your question *all* of the information I mention in my comment. Also, please read the link given in detail.

Comment: @ChadD -- I edited your question a bit, but I might have gotten some of the details wrong (It was a bit unclear).  Please look it over to make sure I got it right.  I am particularly unclear about the last sentence "I would like to print what it matches" (My interpretation of your original).  Could you clarify that a little bit?  What is your desired output exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many different ways to do it. The following is one simple approach

```
list_of_ints=[112, 896, 455, 1164, 1164, 336, 386, 521, 1011, 1033]
list_of_strings=[['ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057393', 'p.Tyr112His', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296091', '-'],
 ['ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057394', 'p.Thr896Ala', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296093', '-']]
for ints in list_of_ints:
    for st in list_of_strings:
        if str(ints) in ','.join(st):
            print st


['ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057393', 'p.Tyr112His', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296091', '-']
['ZNF91', 'Q05481', 'VAR_057394', 'p.Thr896Ala', 'Polymorphism', 'rs296093', '-']
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the revision history for this question, it appears that you are building the list of integers and the list of strings at the same time while iterating over a csv file.  If that's the case, you might want to consider a slightly different data structure:

```
data = defaultdict(list)
with open(csvfile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        number = ...  #parse the number from the line here
        data[number].append(line)
```

Now if you want access to all of the lines which contain the number 112, you can just do:

```
for line in data[112]:
   print (line)
```

If you need the list of numbers, you can get that easily:  `list(data.keys())` (or just `data.keys()` if you're using python 2.x)